# Bing Maps pushpin on Windows 8.1 ARM

Tags: arm, maps, windows-8.1, pushpin

I use next code for binding pushpin source

```
<map:Map x:Name="map" ZoomLevel="9" >
    <map:MapLayer>
        <map:MapItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SearchResult, Converter={StaticResource InvertCollectionConverter}}" >
            <map:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ContentControl Template="{StaticResource SearchResultPushpinTemplate}">
                        <map:MapLayer.Position >
                            <map:Location Latitude="{Binding Converter={StaticResource SearchResultToLocationConverter}, ConverterParameter='lat'}" 
                                          Longitude="{Binding Converter={StaticResource SearchResultToLocationConverter}, ConverterParameter='long'}"/>
                        </map:MapLayer.Position>
                    </ContentControl>
                </DataTemplate>
            </map:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </map:MapItemsControl>
    </map:MapLayer>
</map:Map>
```

Second and all next navigation to page with Bing Map control, clear pushpin. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried...

```
       <map:Pushpin>
            <map:MapLayer.Position>
            <map:Location x:Name="myPinLocation" />
            </map:MapLayer.Position>
        </map:Pushpin>
```

?